# angularjs $apply in login

Tags: angularjs, apply

does this make any sense? I ran across it in a login script.

```
$scope.login = function(){
       //.... call to do login stuff then

       $timeout( function(){
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $rootScope.displayName = val.displayName;
                        $rootScope.userID = authData.uid;


                    });
                }, 100);
```

}

I saw it in my code. I thought apply already ran when a button was clicked. Is there a need to run it again?

Comment: no way..you should not need to run it.as `ng-click` does run digest cycle for you..

Comment: `ng-click` does run a digest cycle, but keep in mind this is in a `$timeout`, so it's outside the scope of the event stack. However, `$timeout` ALSO runs a digest cycle (that's why we use `$timeout` instead of `timeout`) so yeah, it's not necessary to do that.

Comment: I should also clarify that that code block was wrapped in a promise: auth.withpassword().then(funtion(){  ... $timeout( function(){...}) }). Would this make a difference since the digest cycle might have ended by then?

Comment: So was the $timeout also in there besides the promise? Either way, like @HankScorpio mentions, both ways should result in a automatic digest cycle.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't make a difference. The $timeout would still be enough.
The only times I ever need to use `$apply` (or `$digest`) is either in a unit test or in an event listener for non-angular event (jQuery event listener for example).

Comment: @HankScorpio yes, thats what I meant :) I was just wondering if OP replaced the promise with the $timeout in his example.

Comment: @JelleKralt my comment was in response to Bill's comment.

Comment: @HankScorpio d'oh! Never mind then :)

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` runs a `$scope.$apply` once it completes so no, it does not make any sense. My guess is that there is some asynchronous call made somewhere else in your app and this piece of code is trying to wait for that call to be completed, but that's not how it should be done.

Promises or events are what should be used there:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q